# Echo error - PHP

Tags: php, html, compiler-errors, echo

I have a long HTML code which I'm echoing out through the echo code. However I get an error and if I remove the code  on all the lines where it says there's an error I get an error on the body instead. When I try to connect to my page I get this error:

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in
>   C:\wamp\www\Legendary\new\usersettings.php on line 670

http://fiddle.jshell.net/n4a6W/

** EDIT **
I just noticed one of the errors, but the errors with almost all of the  is still there...

Comment: You need to show the code or this will be very hard to help with. :)

Comment: show some code as @AndersHolmström said

Comment: some wrong syntax is there ..may be just above line 670 . check for misplaced "!" or ";"

Comment: You're missing an opening `{` or closing `}` brace or semicolon `;` somewhere in your code. Check in and around line 670.

Comment: @BrianGraham Probably one of those missing as stated by brian above.

Comment: As I said it's a very long code, but okey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a parse error I guess this could be easily located with an IDE that supports php parsing on the fly such as Aptana Studio. Give it a try, I'm pretty sure it will help you find the syntax error easily: [Aptana Studio 3](http://aptana.com/products/studio3/download)